# angularjs add years to max datetime-local via controller

Tags: angularjs, datetime

I'm wondering if anybody had this issue:
In an input datetime-local I want to set the min and the max values in relation with today.

Everything is fine for today (min):

```
var nowDate = Date.now();
$scope.spectacle.nowDate = $filter('date')(nowDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm');
```

But I really don't understand how to add 10 years from now to my max attribute.  I tried a lot of things found on websites but nothing is working out.

Note that it's not critical that we see the real day 10 years from now (leap years calculation...) because I just want a big range for my validation.

EDIT: On a side note: is it the best practice to use the type="datetime-local" for datepicking?  If not, what would constitue the "best and most reliable" way to do that kind of thing in angular (choose a date with min max validation and a time (hour/minute))?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just looking for the JavaScript version of adding 10 years to the current date?

```
var date = new Date();
// Tue Sep 23 2014 17:12:55 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
date.setYear(date.getFullYear()+10)
// Mon Sep 23 2024 17:12:55 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does exactly what I wanted.